# Which is Faster? Value calculation or Formula - Google Sheets Script Editor:

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I would like to know if it's actually faster to...

-**do value calculation directly within the scripts editor**

OR

-**run the script that outputs formulas into cells.**

The following is what I currently have:

```
function recheck_qty(itemname){
    var itemcell = findcellbyvalue(itemname);
    var itemcellrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Inventory').getRange(itemcell);
    var row = itemcell.substring(1);
    var sold = checkqty_sold1(itemname);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Inventory').getRange("D"+row).setValue("=SUM(F"+row+":"+row+","+sold+")");
}
function checkqty_sold1(item) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sold = "";
  var count = 0;
  for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    var sheetname = sheet.getName();
    if(count>0){
      sold += ","
    }
    if(sheetname!='Inventory'){
        sold += 'IF(count(FILTER('+sheetname+'!F2:F,'+sheetname+'!B2:B="'+item+'"))<=0,0,-SUM(FILTER('+sheetname+'!F2:F,'+sheetname+'!B2:B="'+item+'")))';    
        count++;
    }
  } // end of loop
  return sold;
}
```

Previously, I was doing actual calculations for **var sold** and the value of **"SUM(F"+row+":"+row"**. But I realize that the data actually take some time to populate into the cell. Could be due to all the getrange(), getsheets() functions that i'm calling.. but i'm not sure.

Changing to this current one, I was able to make it slightly faster but only at times. It does not always work as fast. Still take sometime to load.

Comment: Hello @Lawrence, thank you for publishing this question. Could you please provide an example Sheets document where you would apply this code? That would allow us to better understand the context and provide you a better answer. Cheers

Comment: Sure. This is the link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nIK8J205Pqjr0l34c3MHyG0ssr1UxbOvBCG3qsepp80/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The issue, according to my calculations and testing with your sheet seems to be mostly coming from the part where you search the item in your 'Inventory' sheet (function `findcellbyvalue()`), especially when you have a large amount of items.  Below I propose a modification that may improve your performance:

#### Modification of `findcellbyvalue()`:

- It doesn't call `sheet.getDataRange()` as it is not needed (you can do `sheet.getLastRow()` instead.
- It uses the [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class to efficiently find the item you desire.

```js
function findcellbyvalue(value) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Inventory');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow-1, 1);

  // returns a range (of the cell)
  var finder = searchRange.createTextFinder(value).matchEntireCell(true);
  return finder.findNext().getA1Notation();
}
```

Further to that I recommend that you visit the following links:

- **Google Apps Script best practices**: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices (especially important: `Use batch operations` section)
- **Boosting Google Sheets performance**: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/#4
- **Troubleshooting - Execution transcript**: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript (this tool will help you profile the time it takes to perform each 'action' in your script).